# Angularjs Promise.all not updating scope, while $q.all does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

I am using Angularjs 1.3.7 and just discovered that Promise.all does not update angularjs view after a successful response, while $q.all does. Is this later changed since Promises are included in native javascript or what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Probably yeah, because the Promise API is not integrated with the angular mechanism - meaning essentially that it doesn't trigger a digest cycle at key point of the lifecycle of the promises. Try adding a $scope.$apply() at the end of the Promise.all() callback function to trigger a digest cycle manually.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding and it helps, I just thought since Angular integrated Promises before native javascript did, they would apply changes automatically, interesting, thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [IAmDranged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813704/iamdranged) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243148/angularjs-promise-all-not-updating-scope-while-q-all-does/41348567#comment69685839_41243148):

> Probably yeah, because the Promise API is not integrated with the angular mechanism - meaning essentially that it doesn't trigger a digest cycle at key point of the lifecycle of the promises. Try adding a $scope.$apply() at the end of the Promise.all() callback function to trigger a digest cycle manually.

It was confirmed that Promise.all does not trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: Related read [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)